# Document "from" or "of" year 1988

Tags: prepositions, vocabulary

If I refer to a document that was written in 1988, which is correct?

> The document of 1988 mentions the birth of a legend.

or

> The document from 1988 mentions the birth of a legend.

Comment: **from** is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Either can be used, with *from* being more natural.  Using *of* would suggest a document that treats of 1988.

Or, better, use neither:

> The 1988 document mentions the birth of a legend.